# Nonlinear animation algorithm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm a programmer working on an animation algorithm. Heuristically, it starts out like this:

```
animate (currentPos, destinationPos, currentFrame, totalFrames) {
     distance = destination - current 
     framesLeft = totalFrames - currentFrame
     moveBy = (framesLeft/distance) 
     //item's position changes by moveBy 
     animate((currentPos+moveBy), destinationPos, currentFrame++, totalFrames);
```

So the function gets called recursively until `currentFrame` = `totalFrame`, calculating a different distance to move by each time. That said, if I do it like I have here, `moveBy` ends up being the same every time. However, I want the animation to be nonlinear, such that the item moves very fast at the beginning of the animation and slowly slides into position at the end.

What can I put in place of `moveBy = (framesLeft/distance)` to achieve this functionality - i.e. that will make moveBy high/low when distance and framesLeft are high/low?

(p.s. sorry the tags are all over the place, I wasn't quite sure where to tag this)

Comment: you can use `framesleft/(2*distance)` . Each time the function is called it will move only half the times it has moved previously . I think you will face this problem here , that if there are 100 frames then it will stop at 97 . But you can overcome that by adding  condition that if `moveby < 1`  then set it equal to `1` . I am not sure if this will work , this is a suggestion .